# Querying on Umbraco Checkboxlist items using Razor

Tags: razor, umbraco, querying

I have the following on my page:

```
var filteredArticles = newsNode.Descendants().Where("newsType.Split(',').Contains('Employer')");
```

newsType is a property on my news items that is an Umbraco checkbox list data type that umbraco renders as a comma delimited list such as :

```
<newsType>Agent,Employer,Provider,Home Page</newsType>
```

I want to just retrieve back all "Employer" articles.  But I receive the following error:

> Umbraco.Core.Dynamics.ParseException: No applicable method 'Split'
>   exists in type 'String'

Is there a different way to query a comma delimited list from a checkbox list using razor?

This is for Umbraco version 7.2.4.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is (Umbraco 7):

`GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<string>>("xxxx").Contains("yyyy")`

Answer (score 0):

First of all which version of Umbraco - 4, 6 or 7?

Secondly you have a list of articles,  that you want to query.

```
newsNode.Descendants()
```

Presumably there is a property on a news article that you wish to filter by - in other words, what, in your news article, would contain the text "Employer" so that you can filter?

Might be easier if you upload the code so we can have a look.

Comment: I have edited my post in order to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking to do:

```
var articles = newsNode.Descendants();
var filteredArticles = articles.Where(article => article.GetPropertyValue<string>("newsType").Split(',').Contains("Employer"));
```

Untested but should work.

Good luck

Comment: If the above solution worked for you, would you mind marking the answer as correct :)